# Dynamic value for grid-size in Spring batch partitioning

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

How to get the value of grid-size in partitioning model from `jobParameters`

```
<batch:job id="JobA" incrementer="runIdIncrementer">
   <batch:step id="masterStep">
    <batch:partition step="JobA.slave" partitioner="transactionPartioner" > 
            <batch:handler grid-size="#{stepExecutionContext[number]}" task-executor="TaskExecutor" />
    </batch:partition>
   </batch:step>
 </batch:job>
```

Can i get the value of grid-size dynamically

Comment: `scope="step"` and `#{jobParameters[...]}"`

Comment: i am not able to make the <batch:partition step="JobA.slave" partitioner="transactionPartioner" >  in step scoped

Comment: yes not able to make any of the above mentioned code to step scope

Answer (score 0):

You can use properties file or environment variable value to setup grid size. Grid size determine how many partition you need so it not a variable you need to change at every job execution.